# iOS SSL Pinning without a certificate using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I am really confused - I enabled SSL pinning mode to be AFSSLPinningModeCertificate, and it worked without my having to put in a certificate. I'm testing using Charles proxy and the program fails to intercept the request/response data. Once I disable it the app works fine as usual.

I'm glad it works, but I really don't understand why - don't you need to put in a certificate in the app for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why it works, I must ask why you want to use that method? If what you say is true and you have to actually attach a cert, that means you have to do a code release each time your certificate changes. That doesn't sound very maintainable to me. Less than ideal. Why not try setDefaultSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey so that it gets the certificates from the server?

Comment: I was actually just looking into that. I'm not really familiar with how this works - how does pinning a public key work?

Answer (score 0):

You could be using one of the preinstalled trusted certificates of Apple and enabling SSLPinning without a certificate file could work for AFNetworking

Here's the list of [Apple's preinstalled trusted certificates list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132)